# Alternative to showing mjpeg in an img-Tag (with Basic-Authentication)

Tags: javascript, html, basic-authentication, chromium, mjpeg

There was an update in Chromium a while back that did introduce a new security "enhancement". They now forbid the usage of basic-authentication in e.g. the source-Attribute of an Image-Element. (See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=305215 for more details)

I'm aware of how unsafe it is to use basic-authentication and that you might as well use no authentication at all. But since in my case, there are a lot of customers out there that have set a username and password on their cameras and those cameras do not support any other authentication mechanism, it is very important to have an alternative.

Does anyone know any other way to show a MJPEG-Stream? (besides using another browser, which is not possible in an Android App e.g.)

Comment: Transferring HTTP Auth credentials this way has never been officially specified for HTTP URLs, that was a thing for FTP addresses mainly. Other browser have been rejecting this for a long time (or at least been asking the user to confirm whether they wanted to send this data whenever they came across such an URL) – so anyone using this did so at their own risk and should have been aware that this might stop working at any point.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617 - basic-authentication is officially specified. Or do I get something wrong here?

Comment: Of course HTTP Basic Auth itself is specified. Passing the credentials via URL is not however.

Comment: So what other chance is there if you want to display a live-stream in a website that is "secured" with credentials. How can you pass the credentials?

Comment: It looks to me like they implemented this weakly, so you can use a hidden iframe to force the auth: http://jsfiddle.net/8xkvar7m/1/ (this img will always look broken but the debugger on a chromebook shows it is reading it if the iframe sets matching basic auth.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without repeatedly making Http requests. Only one will suffice. You can use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to create a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#Methods), access it's [Reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader) and keep reading from the stream.

Once you have the reader keep reading chunks from the stream recursively. Look for the SOI (    0xFF 0xD8) in the byte stream which signals the end of the header and the beginning of the JPEG frame. The header will contain the length of the JPEG in bytes to be read. Read that many bytes from the chunk and any successive chunks and store it into a [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array). Once you've 
successfully read the frame convert it into a blob, create a UrlObject out of it and assign it to the src property of your img object.

You can provide headers and credentials as parameters to the fetch method.

```
fetch("/path/to/mjpeg/stream", {
    Authorization: "Basic dm9yZGVsOnZvcmRlbA=="  
}).then(response => {...})
```

Keep doing this till the connection is closed.

**Shameless plug. Here's a link to a working sample on [github](https://github.com/aruntj/mjpeg-readable-stream).** You can add the headers as required.